# Malformed reply from SOCKS server when using OkHttpClient

Tags: java, rest, okhttp, socks, spring-cloud-feign

I'm sending REST requests in Java using a feign client which works perfectly fine, however when additionally using an OkHttpClient I get an error message

```
Caused by: feign.RetryableException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server executing GET
```

I identified the line of code causing this error which is

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
...
builder.proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress(socksProxyHost, socksProxyPort)));
```

However since I both need the OkHttpClient and to send requests using the feign client I can't just remove this but instead have to find a workaround. Is there a way to reset the proxy settings for as long as I'm sending the requests via feign and set them back afterwards? I tried setting the default proxy server to null using

```
proxySelector.setDefault(null)
```

but that unfortunately didn't resolve my issue.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Create two instances of OkHttpClient, one with the proxy configured and one with none.

```
builder.proxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
```

If you use `OkHttpClient.newBuilder()` to create one client from the other they'll share an `ExecutorService` and other resources.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the Problem by assigning a new ProxySelector instead of the actual proxy. When overriding the select method I made sure the proxy list is empty for requests sent using the feign client:

```
 ProxySelector proxySelector = new ProxySelector() {
            @Override
            public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
                if (uri.toString().contains("HOST_NAME")) {
                    return List.of();
                }
                return List.of(
                        new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress(socksProxyHost, socksProxyPort)));
            }

            @Override
            public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {

            }
        };
        builder.proxySelector(proxySelector);
```